# Different Alt codes with the same codepage

Tags: windows-7, encoding, code-page

Alt+0120 on my computer prints "H" on my computer but on my friend's computer prints "x".
The chcp command on both computers returns 720 as default code page. 
Do you have any idea what is different in our computers?

---

**Update 1**

Here are some of the keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage on my computer:

ACP 1256

MACCP 10000

OEMCP 720

OEMHAL vgaoem.fon

---

**Update 2**

I checked this in the safemode and everything worked normally, so it must be some program meddling in. BTW, I got AutoHotKey uninstalled but the problem persists.

Comment: I get x.  The ASCI table predicts x (for 120).  What's different about your machine I wonder.

Comment: Do you have a laptop or a computer with the FN key? Are you doing this using the numpad (if you have one)

Comment: What happens if you type ALT+00120 (note extra 0)?

Comment: My computer does not have an FN key, this is just a normal keyboard.I used the numpad to type the numbers, Alt+00120 prints H again.

Answer (score 0):

> Code page 437 is the original MS-DOS character set on the PC. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_4… . In this character set, character 236 is ∞ .
>
> But Microsoft later invented other code pages for different languages or to be more similar to the Windows code page 1252. Windows Code page 1252 covers western European languages and is the normal Windows code page installed on computers where the language is set to a form of English. The DOS code page that most closely resembles Windows code page 1252 was originally Code page 850. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_8… . In this code page character 236 has the value ý. When the Euro system € was invented, Microsoft invented yet another DOS code page which they called 858 which was identical to Code page 850, except that it included € instead of ı, the dotless i. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_8… .

You may have have different Code page installed.

I have seen some people report that adding an additional 0 to the start helps. So, you could try <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

Or, you have some mapping tool installed, like AutoHotKey or a clipboard manager which is providing undesired results.

[Source](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100707232758AAY1Urh)

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I have autohotkey on my computer but this was the case even before installing it, may be some other software is causing it. 00120 is also no help.